# Stylecop or equivalent tool for XAML .Net 4.5

Tags: .net, xaml, .net-4.5, stylecop

I want to use StyleCop or any other equivalent tool for XAML. So that I can make my code readable.

How can I do this with any tool?

Please help.

Comment: In VS: Tools->Options...->Text Editor->XAML->Formatting->Spacing. Check the THIRD radio in the first group (make sure the check box is checked) and the SECOND radio in the second group. Hit OK. Go back to your XAML file and use Edit->Advanced->Format Document (Ctrl+K,D - may be other shortcut depending on your settings). This will format the document but, unfortunately, will not re-arrange it. On really big files (>5K lines), when used for the first time it may take a while (have seen examples that churned for more than 40 minutes on a 44K-lines file), the UI of VS will be unresponsive.

Comment: Any tool? I'd use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) as they have some pretty good [XAML Editing Tools](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/xaml_editor.html).